# is it possible to have an if else statement in a pdf export preference in my Indesign script

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

My goal is to export single pages if the variable is single number and spreads if hyphen exists using dialog input. For example export pages 2, 6-7, 10.
var a = 2; var b = 6-7; var c = 10;

I'm trying to see if I can use a if else to detect the hyphen in the variable and set the exportReaderSpreads  pref to true. Something like this below, but it does not work. Any thoughts?

```
if (b.includes(-)) {
   exportReaderSpreads = true;
} else {
  exportReaderSpreads = false;
}
```

Comment: When do you run this code? (Also, I think there should be a bit more than just this snippet?)

Comment: You can use b.indexOf("-"). This is not included in InDesign DOM so you will have to define the prototype yourself. Have a look at this: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/indexof-is-not-a-function/td-p/9050746?page=1